# What is the correct approach to iterating over objects in Angular with TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to iterate over a complex object with ngFor, but I am having issues when using the recommended keyvalue pipe. When I try to pass the key as a parameter to a function I am passing to a component I am rendering inside the ngFor, TypeScript is complaining that "Argument of type unknown is not assignable to parameter of type string".

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | keyvalue">
  <component [onItemUpdate]="onItemUpdate(item.key)"></component>
</div>
```

TypeScript is complaining that the type of item.key is unknown and the parameter for onItemUpdate() should be a string. However, item.key will always be a string. What is the correct approach to this problem?

I have considered trying to convert the object to an array but that seems like a workaround instead of an actual solution to a problem that seems to stem from TypeScript. Is there a way to declare a type for the key in the keyvalue pipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the type for the key and value where you declare the object, e.g:

```
item: { [key: string]: string};
```

Or as a workaround, just change the onItemUpdate function input param type to any. Or even just `onItemUpdate(item.key.toString())`.